# Uploading Photos Issue

Tags: php, image, upload

i have wrote a function that takes a photo upload from a form, creates the file on the server and adds the information to the database, but Im having a nightmare trying to get it to do exactly what i want.

*EDIT*

Currently, it displays the correct error message if the filetype is wrong, and over 3MB but when i try to upload a 17MB .bmp file it cancels and logs me out. It appears to reinitiate my process.php file after it has processed the intended function.

I am baffled, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
    <form action="process.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formUpload">
        <label>Picture:</label>
        <input type="file" name="photo" id="photobrowser" tabindex="4">
        <span class="error"><?php echo $form->error("photo"); ?></span><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="sessionid" value="<?php echo $sessionid; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="subphoto" value="1" />
        <input type="image" src="styling/images/button-add-photo.png" id="subBtn" tabindex="6" />
    </form>
```

process.php

```
 class Process {

function Process(){ /* Class constructor */
    global $session;

    if(isset($_POST['subphoto'])){ /* User submitted an advert photo  */
        $this->procAddPhoto();
    } else if($session->logged_in){ /* No form was submitted therefor logout */
        $this->procLogout();
    } else { /* User trying to view this file */
        header("Location: /");
    }
}
function procAddPhoto(){
    global $session, $form;

    $retval = $session->addPhoto($_FILES['photo']['size'], $_FILES['photo']['type'], $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $_POST['sessionid']);    

    if($retval == 0){ /* Successful */
        // do stuff
    } else if($retval == 1){ /* Errors found */
        // do stuff
    } else if($retval == 2){ /* Adding failed */
        // do stuff
    }
   } // close function procAddPhoto()
 };

 $process = new Process; /* Initialize process */

 ?>
```

session.php

```
function addPhoto($subphotoSize,$subphotoType,$subphotoTmpname,$subsessionid){
    global $database, $form;

    $maxFileSize = 3000000; // bytes (3 MB)

    /* Image error checking */
    $field = "photo";
    if($subphotoSize == 0){
        $form->setError($field, "* No file selected");
    } else {
        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($subphotoTmpname);
        if($width > 4000){
            $form->setError($field, "* Max photo width is 4000 pixels.");
        } else if($subphotoSize > $maxFileSize) {
            $form->setError($field, "* Photo is above the maximum of 3 MB");
        } else if( ($subphotoType != "image/jpeg") && ($subphotoType != "image/pjpeg") && ($subphotoType != "image/png") ){
            $form->setError($field, "* $subphotoType is wrong file type");
        }
    }
    /* Errors exist, have user correct them */
    if($form->num_errors > 0){
        return 1;  //Errors with form
    } else { // Else use variables

        /* Get random string for new filename name */
        $randNum = $this->generateRandStr(10);
        $filerootpath = PHOTOS_DIR.$subsessionid."/";
        $thumbrootpath = PHOTOS_DIR.$subsessionid."/thumbs/";

        if($subphotoType == "image/png"){
            $filename = $randNum.".png";
        } else if ($subphotoType == "image/jpeg" || $subphotoType == "image/pjpeg"){
            $filename = $randNum.".jpg";
        } 
        $fullURL = $filerootpath.$filename;
        $thumbURL = $thumbrootpath.$filename;

        /* Make sure file is RGB colors */
        $getimagesize = getimagesize($subphotoTmpname); 
        if (isset($getimagesize['channels']) && $getimagesize['channels'] == 4 && $getimagesize[2] == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) { 
            $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($subphotoTmpname); 
            if ($im) { 
                imagejpeg($im, $image, 75); 
                imagedestroy($im); 
            } 
        }


        /* Upload files to correct folders */
        move_uploaded_file($subphotoTmpname, "$fullURL");

        /* Use session ID for the advert ID because it hasnt been made yet */
        $userSession = $this->userinfo['userid'];
        $ownerID = $this->userinfo['id'];
        if(!$database->addNewPhoto($ownerID,$fullURL,$userSession,$is_main_photo, $subsessionid, $thumbURL)){
            return 2; // Failed to add to database
        }
    }
    return 0; // Success
}
```

Comment: "unless, the file is several MB in size, in which case it completely logs the user out" Your users will love you for that...

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought... I am guessing that you have more than one issue here.  You said that when someone tries to upload a file over X mb it basically hits the kill switch.  Do you know, roughly, what that size is?  If you do, can you compare it to the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size settings for your php installation?  They should both be visible in phpinfo().  I think that the default is somewhere around 2mb but I could be wrong on that.  Either way, I know that when you try to upload beyond those settings it basically spits the bit.  You may have to change the php.ini settings for that one.

Comment: I changed those values on my php.ini file and the script still does the same. I edited the original post if you dont mind having a look again. Thanks

Comment: Two things to keep in mind.  First, what did you change those values to in php.ini?  It is not well documented, and I probably should have mentioned this in my original answer but I was a bit rushed, but post_max_size must be at least double the size of upload_max_filesize or the settings will be rejected and defaults of 8MB and 2MB respectively will be used.  I would verify that you have those set correctly, then restart php ( if you don't restart the php engine the changes never take effect ) and have a look at phpinfo() just to be sure that it took.  Also...

Comment: I'm really not sure that I understand the issue with not being able to see certain files.  Are you saying that a file will upload properly, but not be viewable in the browser?  Or are you getting the error message in the browser?  If you could clarify exactly when / where that particular error occurs it would help.  Even just providing a link to one of the images that throws this error would help.

Comment: Jeez, one more thing that you should check.  If you are changing post_max_size you need to check if memory_limit is set for your installation.  If this is a shared host then they probably do have a memory limit set.  You will need to adjust the memory_limit so that it is larger than post_max_size.  Those are the three settings that would be shutting you down in php.  memory_limit must be larger than post_max_size.  post_max_size must be at least double the size of upload_max_filesize.

Answer (score 0):

> It displays an error if the filetype isnt correct, unless, the file
> is several MB in size, in which case it completely logs the user out,
> almost like its killing all session variables

Please open /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini (assuming you are using apache2) and set upload_max_filesize = 5M (for 5 megabyte file) and you have file_uploads = On. then restart apache. and try again.

> The image cannot be displayed because it contatins errors." But when i
> download the uploaded image from the server, the picture displays
> fine, but not via http.

can you check you have enough permission to read image from the directory where it is stored. (and make sure you are accessing the right directory; try copying relative path of image in the browser address bar )

let me clear few things first:

1.you can upload 17 mb file but you want to restrict upload more than 3 mb.
2.it uploads 17 mb file but from browser you can see that. but if you download from your server windows can open it correctly.?

can you insert:   var_dump($ubphotoSize); var_dump($$maxFileSize);  at the beginning  of addPhot() and try again. according to you it seems it cannot compare file sizes. please let us know our output.

Comment: It doesnt show on the phpinfo file, i think the host has restricted that. So I am emailing them now to find out what the values are. Thanks

Comment: Im using EasyPHP on my own computer and i have made the upload_max_filesize = 18M and still logs me out. Im uploading a 17Mb .bmp file so either it should say its too large or that its the wrong file type, but it doesnt yet it displays the correct error with a 4 Mb jpg or a .bmp file (not allowed).